# UWP - Windows Cannot Register Package 5ddccc63-e1ef-4118-bf08-bbafc1da427d

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm having a problem with my designer, it cannot render my `xaml` and produced this error. And I have no idea why is this happening, in later days it rendered my project, I'm new with VS2015 Community. Can anyone suggest how do I solve this / or how can I get rid of this error?

[image: error]

Comment: If you create a blank UWP app, could you see this issue? Could you please check that if the app has been installed on this machine? If so, please uninstall it and reopen VS again

Comment: When this was occur, I start a new project, and this issue was not brought up. I wonder why?

Comment: looks like something wrong with your current project, if possible, you can share a minimal sample, I can check it for you

Comment: It was just a simple tutorial I follow from youtube. A simple Button and TextBlock. :) Beginner in `UWP`